# TSQL Execute result different in PHP and SSManagement Studio

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm querying a MSSQL Procedure from PHP and SSManagement Studio and the result is different??

This query is getting the fields starting by tKey from the table. Two columns tKey1 and tKey2 exists

Procedure `sp_myProc`

```
DECLARE @tKeys VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @tKeys = ISNULL(@tKeys + ',', '') + column_name
FROM   testweberp.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE  table_name = myTable
       AND LEFT(column_name, 4) = 'tKey'
ORDER  BY ordinal_position;

SELECT @tKeys
```

When I execute the query from SSMS, exec sp_myProc, i get the result: `tKey1,tKey2`

When I execute the query from php, `mssql_query("exec sp_myProc",$link)`, I get the result: `,tKey1,tKey2`

Yes, there is an extra comma in the result sent to php
And it is not produced by php, because if instead of `@tKeys`, I return the `len(@tKeys)`, it is `11` in SSMS and `12` in php?

Comment: Sure that is your exact code? This would happen if `@tKeys` was being initialised to an empty string rather than was `null`. You might want to look at `XML PATH` to do this concatenation anyway as the method you are using is [not guaranteed to work](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems [SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) may be the culprit.

Using a similar query on one of my databases returns no leading comma for `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON`, and a leading comma for `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF`.

Note that (from MSDN)

> The setting of SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is set at execute or run time and not at parse time.

Comment: You got it right!! Thank you. So it must default to ON in Management Studio and to OFF coming from PHP. Microsoft says _In a future version of SQL Server CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL will always be ON_